# Adding minus sign in a cell

Tags: excel

My problem is having a minus sign added to variation amount of cells...

I have, lets say, 8 cells containing numbers-

```
392567
393231
393471
394154
421015635533
421015964636
42125444
45215544
```

Now I want to add a minus sign between the last and the second last digit, like this: 39256-7

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: In the same cell, or a different cell? Do you want vba or formula?

Answer (score 3):

this simple formula parses it and adds the `-`

```
=REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1),0,"-")
```

[image]

Comment: Reading that formula, and reading the description of that formula that pops up, I would have thought it would have added the dash after the last character.  I was WRONG.

Comment: For some reason I can't make this work. I have a finnish version of Excel and I already tried "Korvaa", which means replace but no help. 
I'm getting the values of the cells from an external software which produces them in .csv -format, does that have anything to do with anything? Though I did save it to .xlsx -format before trying.

Comment: When I write the formula, those inner parenthesis turn to red. Could it be because of Finnish version needs to have different type of parenthesis as inner ones?

Comment: @Petri do you need to use `;` instead of `,` in your formulas?